# geoTest function - creating an if/else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I need a little help tweaking this code.

The task calls for me to declare a new function named geoTest().
It should contain an if/else statement that checks the value of the navigator .geolocation property. If the value is truthy, the function should call the getCurrentPosition() method, running the createMap() function on success or the fail() function on failure. If the navigator.geolocation value is falsy, the function should call the fail() function.

-The timeout is from another step.

Here's my code:

```
function geoTest() {
    var waitForUser = setTimeout(fail, 10000);
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(createMap());
    } else {
        fail();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass callback functions to `getCurrentPosition`. To pass a function as an argument, use the function name **without** putting parentheses after it (parentheses make it call the function immediately and pass the return value to the function).

The instructions say to call `fail()` if `getCurrentLocation()` fails, but you were calling it when `navigator.geolocation` is not set. `getCurrentLocation()` takes a second callback function, which will be called when it fails.

```
function geoTest() {
    var waitForUser = setTimeout(fail, 10000);
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(createMap, fail);
    }
}
```

Your task is almost identical to the example shown in the MDN documentation for [`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition).